# How to create a java client that consumes a webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Well, I've created a webservice that i can find accessing locally at:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/WSPA?wsdl

Now i need to test my webservice by calling it from another java application to verify it its working fine. I've seen that its working using WebService Client from JBoss plugin on eclipse. But the problem is that i have a method wich recieves a list of SoapFile containing a String and array of bytes. And i need to verify if its working.

```
@XmlType
public class SoapFile implements Serializable {

  private String fileName;
  private byte[] fileData;

  public String getFileName() {
     return fileName;
  }

  public void setFileName(String fileName) {
     this.fileName = fileName;
  }

  public byte[] getFileData() {
     return fileData;
  }

  public void setFileData(byte[] fileData) {
     this.fileData = fileData;
  }
}
```

I've not found how to create a simple webservice client that consumes that service to test.
I would like some direction for this... Tutorial or some website that explains how to make it step by step.
How can i create a java client for this webservice?

Comment: Use httpclient library to write client for your service.

Comment: I think most IDE's have a built in option which uses `wsimport`, making your task quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor, just use `wsimport` with your web service url - you will get generated classes for WebService and then just invoke service in that way:

```
ServiceGenerateFromWSImportWhichIsTheSameAsYour iService = 
   new ServiceGenerateFromWSImportWhichIsTheSameAsYour().
            getServiceGenerateFromWSImportWhichIsTheSameAsYourPort();

// now on iServie instance you can invoke method from your webservice
// but you have to use stub classes generated by wsimport

iService.myMethodWhichGetFileList(List<SoapFileStubGeneratedClass> sopaFiles);
```

And `wsimport` is standard java tool in jdk instal folder

More on `wsimport` tool you can find here:

[wsimport doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)

Using `wsimport` in your case will be:

```
wsimport -p generated_classes -s generated_sources http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/WSPA?wsdl
```

and you will find .class files in folder `generated_classes` and .java files in folder `generated-sources`

Comment: SOAPUI (both free or paid version) are a great help too. SoapUI can generate the client files as well, and are useful for testing.

Comment: I've tried that wsimport and got this message: directory not found: generated_sources

Comment: so create those directories first

Comment: one mistake `-p generated_class` means package name to be created (folder with that name is just the effect of creating package structure) so it will be better to use `-p your_app_name`

Comment: I've changed the generated_class to my project name... and now im getting "directory not found: generated_sources"

Comment: but did you create `generated_sources` directory also?

Comment: yes... But im not sure i've created it in right place.. where should i create him?

Comment: Congratulations! if you don't add path to jdk/bin to your `system_path` then your have to go to directory where you want to have your classes/sources generated from `wsimport` and ther use command `path_to_jdk_bin/wsimport wsimport_parameters_from_my_example` or you can user direct not relative directory path to your source folder

Comment: It solved my problem! Now i can make my tests :) I've started the test with "sayHello" method only... Now im gonna add the other method and test it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a WSDL file. If yes then you can use IDE like eclipse to generate client stub.

Below link will also be a good place to start

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish6.html

Answer (score 0):

A "Hello World" Tutorial with `wsimport` for Jax-WS can you find [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)

Tim